# how to draw a dynamic line in threejs with mouse down between two points using buffergeometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to draw dynamic line on mouse events in threejs webgl canvas using buffergeometry with raycasting. Can anyone help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [MeshLine](https://github.com/spite/THREE.MeshLine), Mesh replacement for THREE.Line

Instead of using GL_LINE, it uses a strip of triangles billboarded.

Comment: Thank You Jim . But can You give a fiddle demo for this as i am new to threejs.